# Delete JavaFX table row with delete key

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there a way to delete selected table row using keyboard delete key?

Is there any example with this implementation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure you can. You only have to register an [EventHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) and listen to the specific KeyCode. Following example is for TreeTableView but should be applyable for all TableViews.

```
treeTableView.setOnKeyPressed( new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
{
  @Override
  public void handle( final KeyEvent keyEvent )
  {
    final TreeItem<YourObject> selectedItem = treeTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if ( selectedItem != null )
    {
      if ( keyEvent.getCode().equals( KeyCode.DELETE ) )
      {
        //Delete or whatever you like:
        presenter.onEntityDeleteAction( selectedItem );
      }

       //... other keyevents
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: I figured this myself but while debugging I have to conclude that the KeyCode.DELETE is not the same as the input event. Maybe it's because i'm running it on Linux Mint?

Comment: Just discovered that the setOnKeyTyped will not work; does work with the setOnKeyPressed event. With setOnKeyTyped will return event.getCode() == KeyCode.UNDEFINED

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot I managed to intercept and handle (with my application logic) the `Delete` key (`Del` or `Canc`, as you prefer to call it).
Thanks to some debugging I understand that the `Delete` key is identified with the Unicode code: `\u007F`.
So, the moment I type the key, I read the character and compare it with this code.

Here is a piece of my code that has **nothing** to do with table views but I used it for a TextField.
The important thing is the reasoning.

```java
@FXML
public void myKeyListener(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    //Matches and manage TAB, Enter and Delete buttons
    if ((keyEvent.getCharacter().equals("\t") ||
            keyEvent.getCharacter().equals("\r") ||
            keyEvent.getCharacter().equals("\u007F")    //<-- **THIS** is the important one! *****
    )) {
        //My / your application logic
        keyEvent.consume();     //The documentation says:  "Marks this Event as consumed. This stops its further propagation."
        return;
    }

    //Other logic...

    //Entered only to have test outputs
    System.out.println("getCode: " + keyEvent.getCode());
    System.out.println("getCharacter: " + keyEvent.getCharacter());
    System.out.println("getText: " + keyEvent.getText());
    System.out.println("isMetaDown: " + keyEvent.isMetaDown());
}
```

Outputs:

```
getCode: UNDEFINED
getCharacter: ⍰
getText:
isMetaDown: false
```

I hope it can be useful to someone else.

P.S. I'm using Windows 10 with italian keyboard layout. In case it's relevant.